# Поиск всех подстрок в двоичном коде

Tags: java, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите примерный **план** решение следующей задачи:
Захар очень любит двоичные последовательности, особенно ему нравится их исследовать. У Захара также есть несколько любимых натуральных чисел, например, ему очень нравятся числа N и K. Как-то раз Захар понял, что хочет исследовать двоичные последовательности длины N, в которых каждая непрерывная подстрока, содержащая только единицы, имеет длину ровно K (последовательности, состоящие только из нулей, являются таковыми). Двоичная последовательность – последовательность, содержащая только нули и единицы. Подстрока – некоторое количество непрерывно идущих символов последовательности. Например, если N = 5, а K = 2, то существует 6 последовательностей, которые удовлетворяют этим требованиям: 00000, 11000, 01100, 00110, 00011, 11011. 
Прежде чем исследовать эти последовательности, Захар решил посчитать их количество. Так как Захар очень занят исследованием других двоичных последовательностей, он попросил вас помочь ему.

**Формат файла входных данных**:
В первой строке входных данных содержатся натуральные числа N и K, 1 <= K <= N <= 50.

**Формат файла выходных данных**:
Выведите количество двоичных последовательностей, в которых каждая подстрока, содержащая только единицы, имеет длину ровно K.
Гарантируется, что ответ влезает в 64-х битный тип данных (long long в C++ или int64 в Pascal).

Я думал делать так: брать строку, состоящую из нулей в количестве N, а затем заменять нули на единицы в количестве k, перемещаясь по массиву символов, предварительно увеличивая счетчик значений. Только вот некоторые моменты не задались.

Comment: Так [tag:java] или [tag:алгоритм]? И почему тут должны решать за тебя олимпиадные задачки?

Comment: Решать? Да ни в коем случае. А вот от примерного алгоритма я бы не отказался

Answer (score 1):

Я бы построил 2 бинарных дерева(от 1 и от 0 соответственно)
Вот примерный псевдокод

```
если текущийУзел равен 0, то
    если N - текущаяВысотаДерева > K, то
        следующие узлы могут быть как 1 так и 0(добавляем оба)
    в противном случае
        следующий узел равен 0
в противном случае(текущийУзел == 1)
    если по ребру количество единиц < K, то
        следующий узел равен 1
    в противном случае
        следующий узел равен 0
```

Comment: П.С. За оптимальность решения не ручаюсь, но это всяко быстрее, чем ваш метод